# S3 - give each user access/secret keys for a user data directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it possible to dynamically create an access/secret keys for each user in my system that will allow them to read/write/list contents on a bucket with a specific prefix.

for example: my bucket is userDataBucket.
a user with id 77 is logged in. I would like to send him to the client access/secret so he can work with this directory:

```
s3://userDataBucket/users/77/
```

he must work only with this directory and not have access to any other directory.

is such a thing possible?

Comment: I think what you need is to IAM Roles and bucket policies for each bucket. You can make a bucket policy very strict to where a role and user is denied even if they have full "s3:" Don't give the access/secret to anyone, IAM roles and policies are sufficient. See this [article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/)

Comment: Are your users going to read from/write to this S3 bucket directly using the AWS SDKs or S3 compatible clients? Or are they going to write to this s3 namespace via your application?

Comment: @DaveMaple directly through client SDKs (js, android, ios)

Comment: Do they need permanent (never expiring) credentials or would  temporary cognito credentials work: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-credentials.html?

Comment: How many users are you talking about? Depending on that, there might be different solutions.

Comment: @BrunoReis ideally, scalable up to thousands or even tens of thousands

Answer (score 0):

**note:** you should review [iam limits on users and policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_iam-limits.html). There are limits to scale with finite users/policies, for example, you can only have a max of 5000 IAM users, 250 Roles and 100 Groups. Consider using [temporary credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp.html) if you need a scalable solution.

Here's an IAM policy allowing access to the `/users/${username}` directory in the `userDataBucket` bucket. The policy uses a variable so that whatever user is authenticated would have access to the directory matching their username. You could apply this to the bucket and use it as a global strategy if the plan is to use IAM users.

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowListingWithinUserDirectory",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::userDataBucket"],
      "Condition":{"StringLike":{"s3:prefix":["users/${aws:username}/*"]}}
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowAllActionsWithinUserDirectory",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:*"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::userDataBucket/users/${aws:username}/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

If you want to explicitly identify each user by an auto-increment id an explicit policy would look like this:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowListingWithinUserDirectory",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::userDataBucket"],
      "Condition":{"StringLike":{"s3:prefix":["users/77/*"]}}
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowAllActionsWithinUserDirectory",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:*"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::userDataBucket/users/77/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

The AWS SDKs offer methods to automate the creation of policy documents and the ability to attach them to users and groups. Some example methods from the Java SDK:

[AmazonIdentityManagementClient.createPolicy()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/identitymanagement/AmazonIdentityManagementClient.html#createPolicy-com.amazonaws.services.identitymanagement.model.CreatePolicyRequest-)
[AmazonIdentityManagementClient.attachUserPolicy()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/identitymanagement/AmazonIdentityManagementClient.html#attachUserPolicy-com.amazonaws.services.identitymanagement.model.AttachUserPolicyRequest-)
[AmazonIdentityManagementClient.attachGroupPolicy()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/identitymanagement/AmazonIdentityManagementClient.html#attachGroupPolicy-com.amazonaws.services.identitymanagement.model.AttachGroupPolicyRequest-)

Comment: can this policy be created dynamically for every user?

Comment: @MosheShaham: As requested I've added some example methods from the Java SDK for creating a policy and attaching it to a user or group. The same methods are available in many different SDK languages as well.